# RAID 10: SPAN 2 vs SPAN 4

Tags: raid10

I am currently configuring RAID 10 (first time doing RAID ever) for a server at work. In the Configuration Utility. I am given the option of either span 2 or span 4. Having never done this before, I was curious if someone could tell me the pros and cons of for each span? Thanks

The server is a Poweredge r620 with a PERC H710 mini (Security Capable) RAID controller. I have 8 600GB hard drives. I am creating this server as a network storage drive. I have SQL server historian database whose 1TB storage filled up and after 5 years of logging data.

Comment: What's the server and RAID controller make/model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Span 2 is the more common approach. Striped sets of mirrored-pairs. Of course, you should let us know how many disks you have.

Comment: I imagined that Span 2 is more common because it was the default, but what is the difference between the two? Is one better than the other?

Comment: I think it's the difference between 2-way mirrors and 4-way mirrors. How many total physical disks do you have?

Comment: 8 total physical disks

Comment: Yeah, then it's 2-disk pairs, striped across 4 sets, or 4-disk mirror striped across 2 sets.